how to include button blocks inside an editorjs paragraph block
I am using this editorjs button : https://www.npmjs.com/package/editorjs-button
I want to include 2 buttons for every paragraph block I create. How should I go about this?
I cant find any relevant tool which can help me to create a html-section kind of thing.
